# How can you write to tty files

Tags: shell, console, tty, virtual-console, beep-code

I want to use console API of beep to produce a tone because it has lower latency than the evdev API but doing so is not permitted in a graphical shell.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> opens tty6 and after logging in I can run

```
beep -e /dev/tty6
```

In the graphical shell, tty7, you can't write to /dev/tty7 or any of the other tty files and running beep as root is prohibited.

https://github.com/spkr-beep/beep/issues/6#issuecomment-1264648890

The maintainer said here it's not a good idea for security reasons but I don't intend to use it that way for long.

Comment: There are several solutions listed in the post [How do I make my pc speaker beep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep). One of them may be suitable for your context.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310), but at least we know your X is "how can I make my computer produce a tone with low latency?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> running `beep` as root is prohibited

In my Debian 10 `beep` 1.4.3 *can* be run as root.

My tests indicate `beep` refuses to work when there is `SUDO_UID`, `SUDO_GID`, `SUDO_USER` or `SUDO_COMMAND` in the environment. `sudo` sets these variables for the command it executes.

<sup>Trivia: the variables are the reason `sudo -u "$USER" beep` doesn't work. It's funny it doesn't work because `beep` here gets executed as the invoking user, like sole `beep` without `sudo`.</sup>

I can use `env -u …` to unset the variables, or simply `env -i` to clear the environment:

```
sudo env -i beep -e /dev/tty1
```

(I note I can pick any existing `tty`; prior logging in to the tty is not required). I'm not sure if this will help you get low latency though. `sudo` and `env` are additional programs that will add latency.

Alternatively I can invoke `sudo -i` and `unset` the variables – and then I can call `beep -e …` which will work as root.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could sudo env -i not just be run once to initialize it though and place the beep command inside a function?

Comment: @Deoxal "Could `sudo env -i` not just be run once […]?" – This is what "`sudo -i` and `unset` the variables" does.

Comment: Thanks for that. You said they added additional latency before though so I was confused.